# How to change envelope from address using PHP mail?

Tags: php, email

I am using PHP with Apache on Linux, with Sendmail. I use the PHP [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. The email is sent, but the envelope has the `Apache_user@localhostname` in `MAIL FROM` (example nobody@conniptin.internal) and some remote mail servers reject this because the domain doesn't exist (obviously). Using `mail`, can I force it to change the envelope `MAIL FROM`?

EDIT: If I add a header in the fourth field of the `mail`() function, that changes the `From` field in the headers of the body of the message, and DOES NOT change the envelope `MAIL FROM`.

I can force it by spawning sendmail with `sendmail -t -odb -oi -frealname@realhost` and piping the email contents to it. Is this a better approach?

Is there a better, simpler, more PHP appropriate way of doing this?

EDIT: The bottom line is I should have RTM. Thanks for the answers folks, the fifth parameter works and all is well.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

mail() has a 4th and 5th parameter (optional). The 5th argument is what should be passed as options directly to sendmail. I use the following:

```
mail('to@blah.com','subject!','body!','From: from@blah.com','-f from@blah.com');
```

Comment: Note: You may need to add the sender to /etc/mail/trusted-users as well.

Comment: Couldn't find trusted-users on my machine :/

Comment: @Lucas Oman: +1 your answer is right, just wanted to warn whoever might be interested that on almost all shared hosting services (cPanel/WHM) the PHP mail function 5th parameter `-f ...` is disabled by `SAFE MODE Restriction in effect` and would simply show a PHP Warning without changing the default envelope-from therefor your answer in these cases would not be an option. And regarding Devon comment the `/etc/mail/trusted-users` can not be changed on shared hosting because belongs to the main server configuration.

Comment: Adding to my last comment `safe_mode` is DEPRECATED since PHP 5.3.0 [ref. http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php] therefor if your shared hosting service still has got it you can complain to its tech support. When PHP `safe_mode` is `Off` the Lucas Oman answer works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows (which sends via SMTP).  Only when using sendmail.  For windows you need to modify PHP config or call `ini_set('sendmail_from', 'yourmail@example.com');`.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend checking into [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com). It's great for creating and sending email, making the process a lot easier, along with support for SMTP.

Comment: PHPMailer seems to use exactly the PHP mail 5th paramater `-f ...` as suggested by Lucas Oman in his answer above. You can see it in `function MailSend` in PHPMailer source file `class.phpmailer.php`

Answer (score 2):

[PHP Official documentation for mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string
>   $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`
>
> ...
>
> **additional_parameters (optional)**
>
> The **additional_parameters** parameter can be used to pass additional
>   flags as command line options to the program configured to be used
>   when sending mail, as defined by the `sendmail_path` configuration
>   setting. For example, this can be used to **set the envelope sender
>   address** when using sendmail with the `-f` sendmail option.
>
> This parameter is escaped by `escapeshellcmd()` internally to prevent
>   command execution. `escapeshellcmd()` prevents command execution, but
>   allows to add additional parameters. For security reasons, it is
>   recommended for the user to sanitize this parameter to avoid adding
>   unwanted parameters to the shell command.
>
> Since `escapeshellcmd()` is applied automatically, some characters that
>   are allowed as email addresses by internet RFCs cannot be used. **mail()**
>   can not allow such characters, so in programs where the use of such
>   characters is required, alternative means of sending emails (such as
>   using a framework or a library) is recommended.
>
> The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user
>   to the sendmail configuration to prevent a '`X-Warning`' header from
>   being added to the message when the envelope sender (`-f`) is set using
>   this method. For sendmail users, this file is `/etc/mail/trusted-users`.

Comment: any idea where would i find the equivalent to `/etc/mail/trusted-users` in a non unix environment like shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (im not sure tho):

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", yourmail@example.com);
mail(...);
ini_restore("sendmail_from");
```

Comment: Good idea, I tried this on shared hosting, but unfortunately this is not a workaround because when `safe_mode=On` even the `ini_set("sendmail_from"` is ignored. And when `safe_mode=Off` Lucas Oman answer is easier and faster [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179014/how-to-change-envelope-from-address-using-php-mail/179061#179061]

Comment: This only works on Windows servers (as noted in PHP.ini), but great tip.

Answer (score 0):

following to php manual additinal -f parameter need to be passed to mail function

Not as many write here "-f from@email.com" but without white space "-ffrom@email.com"

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

[image: See example#4 in manual]

Comment: neither way made a difference for me

Answer (score -10):

What you actually need to do is **change** the **hostname** of the machine Apache is running on, plus the **user** Apache is running as.

In your current case it is:

- Apache user:**nobody**
- Server hostname: **conniptin.internal**

Changing those two values is pretty simple and will solve the root of your problem.

Although if you need to do it from PHP then perhaps use the `system/exec` functions. I do not think it will work in practice though, as you need to restart Apache and probably also the entire host for the new names to be used.

Comment: Changing the hostname, and running Apache as a different user, have far-reaching consequences (serious security consequences in the latter case) and are often not permitted by organisation policy or by your shared hosting provider.

Comment: Well, this DID solve MY problems (after some googling)... But I am on a VPS.