# How to change the From Email to be the email that is in the form

Tags: php, email, web

I have the Following form below and i been busting my head trying to figure out how to change the from email address to be different.

Currently its using the php server and the auto-reply on the email that is being used is sending an auto-reply and its just creating a big mess. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {



    //create an empty errors array

    $errors = array();

    //our form has been submitted

    if($_POST['name'] == "") {

        //the name field is empty

        $errors[] = "The name field is empty";

    }

    if($_POST['email'] == "") {

        //the email field is empty

        $errors[] = "The email field is empty";

    }

    if($_POST['comment'] == "") {

        //the comment field is empty

        $errors[] = "The comment field is empty";

    }




    if($_POST['phone'] == "") {

        //the comment field is empty

        $errors[] = "The phone field is empty";

    }


            if($_POST['passengers'] == "") {

        //the comment field is empty

        $errors[] = "The passengers field is empty";

    }



    if($_POST['destination'] == "") {

        //the comment field is empty

        $errors[] = "The destination field is empty";

    }

    if(!stripos($_POST['email'], '@')) {

        $errors[] = "The email address was not valid";

    }

    if(count($errors) == 0) {

        $sendto = "inquiry@maximtours.net";

        $title = "Contact Form";

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $message = "Name: ".$_POST['name']. "\n".
            "Mail: ".$_POST['email']. "\n".
            "Date of Travel: ".$_POST['month'].". " .$_POST['day'].", " .$_POST['year'] ."\n".
            "Phone No: ".$_POST['phone']. "\n".
            "Number of Passengers: ".$_POST['passengers']. "\n".
            "Traveling From: ".$_POST['city']. "\n".
            "Destination: ".$_POST['destination']. "\n".
            "Comment: ".$_POST['comment']. "\n";


        $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


           if(mail($sendto, $title, $message, $email, 'inquiry@maximtours.net'.$email)) {

                $success = true;

            } else {

                $success = false;

            }



    } 
}

?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if($success == true && count($errors) == 0) {

        echo "<h2>Thanks for getting in touch!</h2>";


    }

    if(count($errors) == 0 && $success == false && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        echo '<h2>There was a problem with our form. Please email us directly via inquiry@maximtours.net.</h2>';

    }



    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $success == false && count($errors) > 0) {

        echo "<ul>";

        foreach($errors as $e) {

            echo "<li>$e</li>";

        }

        echo "</ul>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to change about the from address? Is the problem with the envelope sender (in the `mail()` call) or in the `From:` header in the message? Please explain what you expect (or hope to see) and what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 5th argument in the mail() function to the e-mail address you want as the From: email address.

```
mail('to@blah.com','subject!','body!','From: from@blah.com','-f from@blah.com');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/179061/2701758

Answer (score 0):

i think you need some change here

```
mail($sendto, $title, $message, $email, 'inquiry@maximtours.net'.$email)
```

change this to

```
mail($sendto, $title, $message, $headers);
```

and whatever from address you need you can set in $headers.