# php email domain name

Tags: php, email

```
mail("xxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
    'This is the subject!',
    '<div style="background:black;color:green;width:100%;height:1000px;">Email email message message HEy</div>',
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1; From: 1234abc"
);
```

When I send this to my mail, it shows as a black background and green text. But the `From` header doesn't work. It just shows as apache `apache@ns209646.ip-188-165-193.eu` where `188.165.193.158` is my servers ip address.

[image]

Comment: Try `From: 1234abc <1234abc@kas-craft.com>` and separate the headers with new lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change envelope from address using PHP mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179014/how-to-change-envelope-from-address-using-php-mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).

```
$headers = 'From: 1234abc <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

However i suggest using an automated mailer
I use http://swiftmailer.org/ and got rid of a lot of frustration because of headers in mails, also mails look better from spam assassin’s pov

Answer (score 1):

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
... "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nFrom: 1234abc" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows up as 1234abc@ns209646.ip-188-165-193.eu  now

Comment: Feel free to put in a full e-mail address.